# Disable useless [freemark] logs on eclipse console in struts2 project

Tags: java, struts2

How can I disable freemark logs in struts2 project?

I constantly get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIj6V.jpg)tons of useless logs like this:
**DEBUG   15729   [freemark] ():** *************************

I'm using struts 2.5.2 and standard java logging and sysout in code(I'm not using log4j).

In my project I don't have any logging.properties file or struts.properties file.

Under project in Lib folder I am using following jars -

commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.4.jar
commons-io-2.6.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
**freemarker-2.3.28.jar**
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar 
log4j-api-2.8.2jar 
ognl-3.1.21.jar
struts2-core-2.5.20.jar 
struts2-tiles-plugin-2.5.20.jar

As mentioned in the below link solution [Disable Struts2 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132232/disable-struts2-logs?rq=1)

I have tried to include the log4j.properties inside src folder with the same content. But still I am getting those logs.

Comment: Did you put it under `resources` folder and it is still not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732825/573032

Comment: Still getting the redundant logs.